# Active other process's window in Java

Tags: java, swing, jvm

I have two Java swing applications (means running in two JVM). Is there any way to switch between them? Active another application's window by Java code?

Comment: No, there isn't a way in pure Java

Comment: what do you mean by 'switch between them'?  alt+tab will switch between them in once sense...

Comment: See *Communication between local JVMs*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052102/communication-between-local-jvms

Comment: See RMI (Remote Method Invocation): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html

Comment: See `Launcher`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5696404/230513).

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command to execute a proccess");` will run a process. Is this what you want?

Comment: It seems that you want to interact with **already** running JVM process. So, I don't think `Launcher` or `ProcessBuilder` can fit your requirements since it will start a new JVM process. If this is a Windows-based Java Swing Application, you can use JNA to invoke User32 `FindWindow` function to search for a window with a given window title name and set its active state based on its process id.

Comment: @icespace Can you provide more details in your question so that others can understand what you are looking for and let this be off the unanswered list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using JNA. I'll give you some code for Windows (more or less will be for other systems) using Maven:
(sorry but I cannot get formatting right)

1. Create Maven project, and add dependencies:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
       <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
       <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Create interface

   ```
   public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
       User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
       HWND GetParent(HWND hWnd);
       HWND FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);
       HWND SetFocus(HWND hWnd);
       HWND FindWindowEx(HWND hwndParent, HWND hwndChildAfter, String lpszClass, String lpszWindow);
       int GetWindowText(HWND hWnd, char[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
   }
   ```
3. Create class

   ```
   public final class Win32WindowUtils {
       private static final int WIN_TITLE_MAX_SIZE = 512;

       public HWND GetWindowHandle(String strSearch, String strClass) {
           char[] lpString = new char[WIN_TITLE_MAX_SIZE];
           String strTitle;
           int iFind = -1;
           HWND hWnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(strClass, null);
           while(hWnd != null) {
               User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowText(hWnd, lpString, WIN_TITLE_MAX_SIZE);
               strTitle = new String(lpString);
               strTitle = strTitle.toUpperCase();
               iFind = strTitle.indexOf(strSearch);
               if(iFind != -1) {
                   return hWnd;
               }
               hWnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindowEx(null, hWnd, strClass, null);
           }
           return hWnd;
       }
   }
   ```
4. And invoke

   ```
   User32.INSTANCE.SetFocus(Win32WindowUtils.GetWindowHandle(windowTitle.toUpperCase(), null);
   ```

Of course - `windowTitle` is your window title (`String`) that you want to focus.

Comment: Woo! Never expect anyone will take it seriesly. Since my request looks wired. Let me take some time to understand the code. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Actually you can clone my library (Mercurial) to look how things work: [library](https://bitbucket.org/pdrzewin/jnativehook/overview)